# Forming a List from a large string of words

Tags: python

With this code:

```
def createWordList(filename):
    file=open(filename,'r')
    s=file.read()
    file.close()
    L=s.split()
    return L
```

And this text file: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~buoni/cs8/labs/lab05/wordlist.txt

I am to return a list of all the words in the text file.
But when the function is called a la:

```
createWordList('wordlist.txt')
```

My computer (core-i5) takes about 5-10 minutes to perform the task and then ultimately freezes.
It can return the string of individual words in about 2 seconds though.

Comment: Are you trying to `print` the result?

Comment: Are you sure this is the part that freezes? Your word file is less than a megabyte. It should fit into memory just fine. What output do you get?

Comment: (That is to say, do you get any output before it freezes, and if so, what is the output?)

Comment: I'm trying to have it return a List of all individual words. It actually does seem to do that, after about 5-10 minutes IDLE gives me the List, but through that whole time IDLE is un-responsive, and it remains so even after it returns the list. It is also not using all my RAM.

Answer (score 1):

```
f=open('wordlist.txt','r+')
listofwords=[]
for line in f:
    listofwords.append(line)
print(listofwords)
```

I faced no problem. took exactly 0.049 sec to form the list(process program without print). printing will take lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The 'file' object is a iterable, and you can iterate it with a 'for' stament.  This is more memory efficient.  Read this: [Methods of File Objects](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

So, try this code:

```
def createWordList(filename):
    myList = []
    input_file = open(filename, mode='r')
    for line in input_file:
        myList.append(line)
    return myList
```

**How works:**

- First, create the empty list.
- Open the input_file.
- Iterates the file object line by line.
- Append each line to the list.
- Then, return the list.

It takes no more than 3 seconds in process the whole file.